# wxFreeChart and -mthreads

Tags: windows, cross-platform, wxwidgets, mingw32

I’m trying to develop some plotting apps for Windows platform. I’m using Debian and built wxWidgets for cross-compiling as described [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Cross-Compiling_Under_Linux).
With MinGW compiler it works perfect and I have no problem with creating Win32 apps under Linux. But I faced some troubles with wxFreeChart.
I run `./configure --host=i386-mingw32 --with-wx-config=/usr/local/i586-mingw32/bin/wx-config`
Then I run 'make' and getting error about

> unrecognized command line option ‘-mthreads

Full output here:

> ~/dev/freechart/bk-deps g++ -c -o wxfreechart_lib_legend.o -I./include -I/usr/local/i586-mingw32/lib/wx/include/i586-mingw32msvc-msw-unicode-static-3.0 -I/usr/local/i586-mingw32/include/wx-3.0 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=unknown -D__WXMSW__ -mthreads  -O2 ./src/legend.cpp
>   g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mthreads’
>   make: *** [wxfreechart_lib_legend.o] Error 1

The only advice I've seen was to remove '-mthreads' from code, but I have no idea where is it(

Comment: It probably comes from `wx-config` output, and while I don't know why is it there in the first place you could edit `/usr/local/i586-mingw32/bin/wx-config` and remove this option from there as a quick hack.

Answer (score 0):

Problem described above is solved, but still no luck with building wxFreeChart.
Next errors I get were about some additional libs, which I finally solved by
`CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include -I~/dev/wxWidgets-3.0.2/include" ./configure --host=i386-mingw32 --with-wx-config=/usr/local/i586-mingw32/bin/wx-config`
I'm not sure that including **.h** from source folder `~/dev/wxWidgets` is a good idea, but at least it solved some problems.

Now **make** crashing with messages like:

`In file included from /usr/local/i586-mingw32/include/wx-3.0/wx/wx.h:17:0,
                 from ./include/wx/wxfreechartdefs.h:20,
                 from ./include/wx/legend.h:13,
                 from ./src/legend.cpp:10:
/usr/local/i586-mingw32/include/wx-3.0/wx/list.h: In constructor ‘wxListKey::wxListKey(const wxString&)’:
/usr/local/i586-mingw32/include/wx-3.0/wx/list.h:381:40: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class wxString’`
or
`/usr/local/i586-mingw32/include/wx-3.0/wx/containr.h:247:13: error: incomplete type ‘wxNavigationEnabled<wxControl>::BaseWindowClass {aka wxControl}’ used in nested name specifier
make: *** [wxfreechart_lib_legend.o] Error 1`